# Additional Parameters to ops.RegisterGradient tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I profusely apologize in advance if the wording of this question is ambiguous.

From https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#implement_the_gradient_in_python
I learnt how to implement a (custom) gradient in python. In principle, the function _zero_out_grad can have arbitrarily many parameters (since it is a python function). For example, let us assume that _zero_out_grad has 3 parameters -
 op, grad, and a tensor "t" i.e. _zero_out_grad(op, grad, t).

The entry point to the python function would be a call to tf.minimize, or tf.gradients, or tf.compute_gradients. My question is: how do I pass the third parameter ("t") to _zero_out_grad, through one of these functions, if at all?

In the case of tf.gradients, I observe that a call to tf.gradients makes an underlying call to "grad_fn(op, *out_grads)" - line 562 - in tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py - a function that takes in only 2 parameters.

Comment: `*out_grads` actually takes an arbitrary about of parameters, and presents itself as a tuple called out_grads. Try searching for `parameter expansion in python`

Comment: Thanks @shadow. I did not think of that.

Comment: Hey @shadow - I thought about this a little more, and suspect this doesn't achieve what I want it to. Adding it to *out_grads ensures that the gradient of op is computed with respect to the individual contents of *out_grad. I do not want the computation of the gradient of op with respect to "t". I think the gradient computation is called through the _MaybeCompile method found at tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py (same place where the method tf.gradients is also defined) , but I'm not sure if this is indeed the case :(